# Performing an operation between two HashMaps by using STREAM API

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I have two HashMaps in the form

```
Map<Integer, Map<String,Double>> MAP_1
Map<Integer, Map<String,Double>> MAP_2
```

Let INNER be the inner map, i.e.

```
Map<String,Double>
```

For each pair of corresponding keys, I want to perform an operation (e.g. subtraction) between the two inner maps. In turn, this operation should be performed between two corresponding keys of the inner maps.
The resulting map should be

```
Map<Integer,List<Double> RESULT
```

Sample maps are

```
MAP_1
------------------------------
|      |  2016-10-02   10.0   |
| ID1  |  2016-10-03   20.0   |
|      |  2016-10-04   30.0   |
------------------------------
|      |  2016-10-02   1.00   | 
| ID2  |  2016-10-03   2.00   |
|      |  2016-10-04   3.00   |
------------------------------

MAP_2
------------------------------
|      |  2016-10-02   2.00   |
| ID1  |  2016-10-03   3.00   |
|      |                      |
------------------------------
|      |  2016-10-02   1.00   | 
| ID3  |  2016-10-03   2.00   |
|      |  2016-10-04   3.00   |
------------------------------

RESULT
---------------
|      |  8.00 |
| ID1  |  17.0 |
|      |       |
---------------
```

So, regarding the outer maps, only ID1 has to be taken into account; in turn, the operation has to involve the inner (common) keys '2016-10-02' and '2016-10-03'.

Here my current code

```
 Set<Integer> common_keys = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(map1.keySet());
    common_keys.retainAll(map2.keySet());
    System.out.println("Common keys: "+common_keys.toString());

    map1.forEach((k,v) -> {

        Map<String,Double> submap_1 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Double>(v);
        Map<String,Double> submap_2 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Double>(map2.get(k));

        Set<String> commons = new LinkedHashSet<String>(submap_1.keySet());
        commons.retainAll(submap_2.keySet());

        System.out.println(k+" : common days: "+commons);


        List<Double> val1 = submap_1.keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(c -> commons.contains(c))
                .map(c -> submap_1.get(c))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Double> val2 = submap_2.keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(c -> commons.contains(c))
                .map(c -> submap_2.get(c))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Double> ABS = IntStream.range(0, val1.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> val1.get(i) - val2.get(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        diff_abs.put(k, ABS);
        });
```

Is there a simpler and smart way to do this, by using JAVA 8' STREAM API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why this urge to use the stream API? If conventional code works for you, just use conventional code.

Comment: I'm already using the stream API in my code. I was wondering whether it exists a more compact way to achieve the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few points on your example above. My go-to implementations for `List`, `Set`, and `Map` are `ArrayList`, `HashSet`, and `HashMap` unless I need something specifically provided by their `Linked` implementations, aka, consistent order (but this happens exceedingly rarely).

Here's how I would approach this:

```
public static <T, S> Map<T, List<Double>> method(
        Map<T, Map<S, Double>> map1,
        Map<T, Map<S, Double>> map2)
{
    Set<T> commonKeys = intersection(map1.keySet(), map2.keySet());

    return commonKeys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            key -> {
                Map<S, Double> inner1 = map1.get(key);
                Map<S, Double> inner2 = map2.get(key);

                Set<S> innerCommonKeys = intersection(
                        inner1.keySet(),
                        inner2.keySet());

                        return innerCommonKeys.stream().map(innerKey ->
                                inner1.get(innerKey) - inner2.get(innerKey))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }));
}

private static <T> Set<T> intersection(Set<T> set1, Set<T> set2) {
    Set<T> intersection = new HashSet<T>(set1);
    intersection.retainAll(set2);
    return intersection;
}
```

And here is a "test" to show that it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Double> inner11 = new HashMap<>();
    inner11.put("2016-10-02", 10.0);
    inner11.put("2016-10-03", 20.0);
    inner11.put("2016-10-04", 30.0);
    map1.put("ID1", inner11);
    Map<String, Double> inner12 = new HashMap<>();
    inner12.put("2016-10-02", 1.00);
    inner12.put("2016-10-03", 2.00);
    inner12.put("2016-10-04", 3.00);
    map1.put("ID2", inner12);

    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Double> inner21 = new HashMap<>();
    inner21.put("2016-10-02", 2.00);
    inner21.put("2016-10-03", 3.00);
    map2.put("ID1", inner21);
    Map<String, Double> inner22 = new HashMap<>();
    inner22.put("2016-10-02", 1.00);
    inner22.put("2016-10-03", 2.00);
    inner22.put("2016-10-04", 3.00);
    map2.put("ID3", inner22);

    System.out.println(method(map1, map2));
}
```

Output: `{ID1=[8.0, 17.0]}`

Comment: Sometimes, in my application, I need that a processing doesn't disarrange the order of the keys; moreover, adding (key,value) pairs to a HashMap has to result in appending the new keys. For this reason I used the `Linked` implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Creating the `Set` is unnecessary. Replace this with a check for `null` in for the same key in the other map. Furthermore creating copies of the maps is unnecessary, since the maps are never modified in the method.

```
public static <T, U> Map<T, List<Double>> merge(Map<T, Map<U, Double>> m1, Map<T, Map<U, Double>> m2) {
    Map<T, List<Double>> result = new HashMap<>();
    m1.forEach((k, v) -> {
        Map<U, Double> v2 = m2.get(k);
        if (v2 != null) {
            // both outer maps contain the same key
            ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
            v.forEach((innerK, innerV) -> {
                Double d = v2.get(innerK);
                if (d != null) {
                    // matching key in both inner maps
                    list.add(innerV - d);
                }
            });
            // list.trimToSize();
            result.put(k, list);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a re-usable method for merging two maps by retaining common keys only and applying a function to both values:

```
public static <K,V,R> Map<K, R> merge(Map<K,V> map1, Map<K,V> map2, BiFunction<V,V,R> f) {

    boolean hasOrder=map1.entrySet().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.ORDERED);
    return map1.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(hasOrder? LinkedHashMap<K,R>::new: HashMap<K,R>::new, (m,e)-> {
            V v2 = map2.get(e.getKey());
            if(v2!=null) m.put(e.getKey(), f.apply(e.getValue(), v2));
        }, Map::putAll);
}
```

Then, you can easily implement the merging of nested maps by using the method twice:

```
public static <K1, K2> Map<K1, List<Double>> merge(
    Map<K1, Map<K2, Double>> map1, Map<K1, Map<K2, Double>> map2) {

    return merge(map1, map2,
        (a,b) -> new ArrayList<>(merge(a, b, (x,y) -> x-y).values()));
}
```

Note that the code above is smart enough to create a `LinkedHashMap` if, and only if, the first map has an intrinsic order, e.g. is itself a `LinkedHashMap` or `SortedMap`, and a plain `HashMap` otherwise. The order of the second map is not retained anyway, which is not an issue if, as your original code seems to assume, both maps have the same order. If their order differs, there’s obviously no way to retain both orders.